# Change default Identity routes in an Angular & ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I configured Angular to use "login" route  to show a `LoginComponent` page. That's ok.

But when I try to access some authorized page without login made, I got the following address in browser:

```
https://localhost:5001/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fapi%2FMyController%2FMyAction
```

and this error:

> The default Identity UI layout requires a partial view '_LoginPartial' usually located at '/Pages/_LoginPartial' or at '/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial' to work. Based on your configuration we have looked at it in the following locations:
>   /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_LoginPartial.cshtml
>   /Areas/Identity/Pages/_LoginPartial.cshtml
>   /Areas/Identity/Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
>   /Areas/Identity/Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
>   /Pages/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
>   /Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml

Is it possible to point to /login page instead of `/Identity/Account/Login` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to configure the app's cookie in Startup.ConfigureServices. `ConfigureApplicationCookie` must be called after calling `AddIdentity` or `AddDefaultIdentity`:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{               
      options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from the api-authorization.module.ts file within the ClientApp.
Add  `{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },` to the RouterModule.forChild([]) array.